# Splitting a string via regex problems

Tags: python, regex, string, split

New to python and I'm having trouble getting the function i want out of regex. Basically i have a string that looks like `"Hello,   World,  Nice"` and i need to convert it into a list with the delimiter being `,`. End result should look like `['Hello', 'World', 'Nice']`

`re.split(',', string)`

Basically the result i get is 
`['Hello', '  World', '  Nice']`.
I know a solution via a different method but i'd like to uses regex.

help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming, that the whitespace can be arbitrary, there are two solutions, that come to mind:

```
re.split(r'\s*,\s*', string)
#          ^- zero or more whitespace incl. tabs and newlines
# the r'' syntax preserves the backslash from being interpreted
# as escape sequence
```

and

```
map(str.strip, string.split(','))
#   ^- apply the 'strip' function (~ 'trim' in other languages) to all matches
```

I'd go with the later. The advantage, if you split often in your code, is to skip the regex machine (although it won't sum up, until you split *really* often).

Comment: The `r` raw string protection can be removed, because `\s` is not interpreted by Python.

Comment: What do you mean by "The advantage, if you split often in your code, is to skip the regex machine"?  Using the splitting function `re.compile('\s*,\s*').split` is slightly faster than the `map(str.strip, s.split(…))` approach, with Python 2.7 on OS X.

Answer (score 3):

Ha, another solution w/o regexp:

```
x="Hello, World, Nice"
[y.strip() for y in x.split(",")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Split on `', '`, with a space

```
re.split(', ', string)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = "Hello, World, Nice"
>>> a.split(", ")
['Hello', 'World', 'Nice']
>>>
```

using re:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split(', ',a)
['Hello', 'World', 'Nice']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
re.split(', ', string)
```

does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have specific advanced requirement, there is really no need for re module.

```
>>> "Hello, World, Nice".split(",")
['Hello', ' World', ' Nice']
>>> map( str.strip, "Hello, World, Nice".split(",") )
['Hello', 'World', 'Nice']
```

if you really insist on re.

```
>>> re.split('\s*,\s*', "Hello, World, Nice" )
['Hello', 'World', 'Nice']
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more robust solution:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile(' *, *')
>>> l = "Hello,  World , Nice"
>>> pattern.split(l)
['Hello', 'World', 'Nice']
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this regex for split

```
>>> a = "Hello, World, Nice"
>>> a.split("[ ,\\,]")
```

in regex first is space and second is comma

Comment: That's no regex split. `str.split()` doesn't use regex. And if it would, it would split a `"Hello World"` too.